# VBA if cells on sheet 1 match cells on sheet 2 - delete row?

Tags: vba, excel

I have two worksheets, sheet 1 and sheet 2.

On sheet 1 I have created a form which allows users to enter values into cells B21, B26, I21, I26, P21, P26.

Then by clicking submit, the data gets inserted onto sheet 2 in columns A,B,C,D,E and F on the next available row.

I am also trying to create a macro that once run, will delete the row on sheet 2 where the values match those on sheet1.

At the moment i am keeping it simple by using an IF statement, but this gives me a type mismatch error.

```
Sub QuickCull()

If Sheets(1).Range("B21").Value = Sheets(2).Range("A:A").Value And _
    Sheets(1).Range("B26").Value = Sheets(2).Range("B:B").Value And _
    Sheets(1).Range("P21").Value = Sheets(2).Range("C:C").Value And _ 
    Sheets(1).Range("I21").Value = Sheets(2).Range("D:D").Value And _
    Sheets(1).Range("I26").Value = Sheets(2).Range("E:E").Value And _
    Sheets(1).Range("P26").Value = Sheets(2).Range("F:F").Value Then

    Rows(ActiveCell.Row).EntireRow.Delete
End If

End Sub
```

Please can someone show me where i am going wrong?

Comment: you need to replace all your `If`s with `Match`. For instance, replace `If Sheets(1).Range("B21").Value = Sheets(2).Range("A:A").Value` with `If Not IsError(Application.Match(Sheets(1).Range("B21").Value, Sheets(2).Range("A:A"), 0)) Then` .

Comment: have you tested the code in my answer ? any feedback ?

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to see if the first condition is met, so we will look for the value in Range("B21") through the entire Column A in `Sheets(2)` using the `Match` function. If it return a successful match, we will then use that result (`RowMatch` representing a row number).

Second, we need to check that all other `If` have matching values in `RowMatch` in `Sheets(2)`. If it does, then we can delete that row in `Sheets(2)`.

Try the **code** below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub QuickCull()

Dim RowMatch As Long

With Sheets(2)
    If Not IsError(Application.Match(Sheets(1).Range("B21").Value, .Range("A:A"), 0)) Then
        RowMatch = Application.Match(Sheets(1).Range("B21").Value, .Range("A:A"), 0)

        If Sheets(1).Range("B26").Value = .Range("B" & RowMatch).Value And _
            Sheets(1).Range("P21").Value = .Range("C" & RowMatch).Value And _
            Sheets(1).Range("I21").Value = .Range("D" & RowMatch).Value And _
            Sheets(1).Range("I26").Value = .Range("E" & RowMatch).Value And _
            Sheets(1).Range("P26").Value = .Range("F" & RowMatch).Value Then

            .Rows(RowMatch).Delete
        End If

    End If
End With

End Sub
```